# Magento 2 not running after migration

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

I've migrated my shop to another server but getting following error, even

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

couldn't help.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:559:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Catalog schema: current version - 2.1.4, required version - 2.1.3
Magento_Catalog data: current version - 2.1.4, required version - 2.1.3
Magento_Quote schema: current version - 2.0.4, required version - 2.0.3
Magento_Quote data: current version - 2.0.4, required version - 2.0.3
Magento_Usps schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Usps data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0";i:1;s:2711:"#0 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#2 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#5 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#8 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 /home/blackdee/public_html/project/LCS-Webshop/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/project/LCS-Webshop/";s:11:"script_name";s:30:"/project/LCS-Webshop/index.php";}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your using the same magento version on both, you can run `php bin/magento --version` on both hosts to check

Comment: yes both are Magento CLI version 2.1.7

Comment: Change schema and data version of Magento_Catalog, Magento_Quote, Magento_Usps.

Comment: thanks @DhadukMitesh worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `schema` and `data` version of,

- Magento_Catalog
- Magento_Quote
- Magento_Usps

And then check it.

Answer (score 0):

In the table **setup_module**, you need to find 3 things:

**Magento_Catalog, Magento_Quote, Magento_Usps**.

Then, their **current version** and the **required version** need to be set in the **same version**.